# Validating username and password in a seperate txt file

Tags: c++

My program asks for id and pw and is supposed to check it against an id and pw in a txt file but I'm not sure what's going wrong. the getLogin function works fine, I think the issue might be in the validateLogin function or showResult function.

The txt file reads:
tommy (enter)
12345

When I enter the same id and pw and go through the program I get the "Invalid" output from showResult.
Any Suggestion?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void getLogin(string & id, string & pw);
bool validateLogin(string id, string pw);
void showResult(bool result);

int main()
{
    string id;
    string pw;
    bool result;

    result = validateLogin(id, pw);

    getLogin(id, pw);
    validateLogin(id, pw);
    showResult(result);

    return 0;
}

void getLogin(string& id, string& pw)
{
    cout << "Enter your ID:  ";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Enter your password:  ";
    cin >> pw;
}

bool validateLogin(string id, string pw)
{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    bool result;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("c:\\login.txt");

    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "File failed to open.";
    }

    inFile >> str1 >> str2;

    inFile.close();

    if ((str1 == id) && (str2 == pw))
    {
        result = true;
    }

    else
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

void showResult(bool result)
{
    if (result == true)
    {
        cout << "Valid.";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid.";
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean to call `validateLogin` twice? `result` is only set from the first call when the username and password aren't set

Comment: Why do you call "validateLogin()" before getting the login values you want to validate?

Comment: wow that was an easy fix. i removed the second call and set result = validateLogin after the getLogin function call and it works fine now. Thanks guys @AlanBirtles

Comment: Also note you NEVER store passwords in a text file in the real-world. You hash the user password when the user sets it and store the hash in the file. Then on all subsequent login attempts, you read the password entered by the user, hash that and then compare the current hash to the one stored in the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah this is just for an intro level c++ class but it definitely seemed like not the best way to do it. thanks for the input